# Moving a thread to another thread while both threads are in use

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
// threadMovedFixed.cpp

#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
#include <utility>

int main(){ 

  std::thread t([]{std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;}); 
  std::thread t2([]{std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;}); 
  
  t.join();
  t = std::move(t2); 
  t.join(); 
  
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "t2.joinable(): " << t2.joinable() << std::endl;

}
```

I am looking at the following snippet, and it seems there are several issues here.

(1) `t2` is being moved to `t` while `t2` while it may be in the middle of  executing its lambda. What happens to `t2` in this case? Does `t2` terminate right away and `t` re-executes `t2`'s lambda from the the beginning, or does it pick up where `t2` left off?

(2) `t` is receiving `t2`, but `t` could be in the middle of its execution of the lambda. What happens here? Does `t` terminate its own call immediately upon receiving `t2`?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem by using `std::move` on `std::thread`? Or are you solving the bug cause by this snippet which is not written by you? Please provide more context because this snippet seems weird..

Comment: @LouisGo This is a snippet from an online MOOCs course for C++ multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that C++ doesn't implement all the multithreading stuff but delegates that to OS. C++ multithreading classes are just wrappers with a convenient interface that follows C++ idioms.

So, there is no problem in moving a running thread to another `std::thread` object. Otherwise (look on it from another angle) why does `std:thread` even have a move constructor? Actually all the OS threads are running even without knowing that C++ has a wrapper. The OS thread (e.g. pthread) continue running being wrapped with another object.

Regarding your second question, `t` is not in the middle of it's execution cause it is already in non-joinable state.

Comment: What happens to the callable unit for `t2` when it is being moved and if it has not been completed?

Comment: @structuralengin, first, it is in a *consistent* state: that is the rule of moving operations. The only consistent state for the thread after another object steals it guts is to be non-joinable.

Comment: AH I see. So if, say, `t2` only finished half of the lambda call before the callable unit gets stolen by `t`, would `t` finish the remainder of the callable unit or does it start over?

Comment: Neither of the C++ objects "finish" the execution. That is the pthread or Windows Threads responsibility. C++ just provides you the access to their statuses and APIs. So in your case in the beginning both `std::thread` have the ownship over the OS threads and are joinable. After you join the `t` it becomes non-joinable. That doesn't matter if `t2` is finished or not -- when you move it to `t` you make `t` joinable again and `t2` non-joinable, while the OS-thread (pthread) is running without knowing that you move the classes.

Comment: It took me awhile to wrap my head around this, but I think I understand now. I can think of `std::thread` as just a wrapper around some low level pthread. So in this case if `t2` essentially owned some pthread, when `std::move(t2)` is called, the ownership of that pthread is transferred to `t`. So there's no transferring of "threads" going on here. Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct. Please remember that moving the system object is pretty simple cause almost everything that you need to move is the handle. Or there is an implementation object, and you just need to swap two pointers.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to t2 in this case?

It will no longer refer to a thread of execution.

> Does t2 terminate right away

`std::thread` object isn't something that can be terminated. It potentially refers to a thread of execution which is something that can conceptually terminate. That thread of execution is not affected by the move. After the move, `t` refers to the thread of execution instead.

> but t could be in the middle of its execution of the lambda.

`t` has been joined, and therefore it no longer refers to a thread of execution until `t2` is assigned to it.

If `t` was joinable, then `std::terminate` would be called (which terminates the process).

Comment: So in this case if `t = std::move(t2)` is called in the middle of the lambda function call, the remaining work would be moved to `t`, so `t` picks up where `t2` left off?

Comment: @structuralengin, it doesn't "pick up where the other is left off": it just steals the handler to the OS thread that is running without knowing of your classes.